# Django admin site, html tags

Tags: html, django

When I write html tags in a text field in the django admin pages and I display them in my own view the html tags are not evaluated. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your template, use [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std%3atemplatefilter-safe):

```
 {{ myobj.html_field|safe }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#std%3atemplatefilter-safe) filter in your template:

```
{{object.body|safe}}
```